# Antd form input double validation

Tags: reactjs, antd

So, i'm new to AntD and i need to setup up a rule for input field, so it could get phone number or email.
I'm trying something like that but it doesn't work as it should:

```
<Form.Item
                            name="contact-info"
                            rules={
                                [
                                    {required:true, message: 'Укажите контактные данные', type: "email"},
                                    {required:true, message: '', type: "number"}
                                ]
                            }
                        >
                            <Input placeholder='Телефон или e-mail' className="form-grid-input"/>
                        </Form.Item>
```

Update: The error, that occurs is that when I input phone number, it still doesn't pass the validator. But, when I input email, everything is all right
[Trouble screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgkmz.png)

Comment: what is its behavior any error ?

Comment: @AqibJaved Added update about error in the post

Comment: the reason your phone number validation is not kicking off is that you have not passed any message its message='' , in the rules its empty make it like this {required:true, message: 'what ever message you wanna show', type: "number"}

Comment: @AhmedHosny even if I pass a message, it still doesn't pass phone number through validator

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов i have posted an answer please check

Answer (score -1):

when using `antd`  follow these steps, for more info please check [antd official documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/)

```
<Form
          name="basic"
          labelCol={{
            span: 8,
          }}
          wrapperCol={{
            span: 16,
          }}
          initialValues={{
            remember: true,
          }}
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          autoComplete="off"
        >
          <Form.Item
            label="email"
            name="email"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'email is required',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
    
          <Form.Item
            label="phoneNumber"
            name="phoneNumber"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'phone number is password!',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
    
          <Form.Item
            wrapperCol={{
              offset: 8,
              span: 16,
            }}
          >
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
```

Comment: I do understand, how simple validation works, but still, what about double validation? (phone number or email)

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов in antd input or fields are separately validated , so if u want to validate email validate it on the email input , if phone number then validate it phone number input

Comment: i ve updated the answer in accordance to your needs please check